# preg_match get div content with two classes

Tags: preg-match, preg-match-all

i have these code..

```
<div class="col-sm-2 title">
   <a href="/products/test.html">Product 1</a> </div>
```

I'm new to to this concept.. I want the preg_match code for that..

Comment: what do you want to match? the whole thing? Perhaps reading about preg_match will help you - e.g. [this php cookbook excerpt](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/webprog/pcook/ch13_08.htm) or the example #2 on [the php manual page for preg_match_all()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php)

Comment: @SARAN I would like to help you find resolution with this question.  Can you expand your question to explain what you are trying to do?  Do you want to capture `/products/test.html`?  or the `Product 1`? or something else?  Does your sample represent a larger piece of data -- meaning, do you need to match these values once or match several values because there will be multiple div's in your real case?